# How can I add an extra field to checkout form in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need to add an extra field to the checkout form.
This doesn't appear to be in checkout.liquid.

How can I add and submit the new field?

Comment: What is it that you want to capture?

Comment: A post code in a seperate field

Answer (score 1):

If this is a PLUS shopify account you can achieve this using some JS.

Depending on what you want to submit you may require a custom App to update the current checkout.

I haven't tried yo use replace in the checkout liquid output in order to add something but I don't think that will be good approach even if it was possible.

Another approach may be to use an external checkout system that allows field control but this may be overkill only for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I am using a Shopify PLUS account. Shopify support have said it's possible using some JS but I'm not really sure where to start?

Comment: This https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/layouts/checkout is a good place to start.

Comment: And this https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/layouts/checkout/best-practices is where you would go next.